# 'I am an M.A in History from XYZ university' - Is it correct way to refer myself?

Tags: word-choice, writing-style

I was writing my cover letter for applying some where.

I have done my Master's in History from XYZ university. How can I refer my self ?

My Attempt : I was thinking to refer my self as a Postgraduate in History. Then I thought it will sound like I am currently doing my Master's. Then I thought I will write that I am an M.A in History from XYZ university.

Have I gone wrong anywhere?

Comment: What's wrong with "I have an MA in History"? That would be the usual way of referring to a qualification in English.

Comment: in English ?@StuartF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/postgraduate?q=postgraduate)) **postgraduate** n. a person who already holds a first degree and who is doing advanced study or research; a graduate student

[Postgraduate education](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postgraduate_education), [Degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postgraduate_education#Degrees)

"Postgraduate in History" is apparently not used ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=postgraduate+in+History&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=)). You do find "postgraduate in mathematics" although it is not used continuously ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=postgraduate+in+mathematics&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpostgraduate%20in%20mathematics%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpostgraduate%20in%20mathematics%3B%2Cc0)), and "postgraduate in physics" ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=postgraduate+in+physics&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpostgraduate%20in%20physics%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpostgraduate%20in%20physics%3B%2Cc0)). Nevertheless, using the term "postgraduate in History" seems justified, but on the condition that you keep on being a student; for instance while holding an MA you go on working towards a doctorate.

So, if you go on with your studies while working or trying to obtain some work you could say that you are a postgraduate in History with an MA; as well, "a postgraduate with an MA in History" would do. You could also say that you pursued your studies at the postgraduate level and were recently awarded your MA in History from XYZ University. Otherwise, that is, if you are finished with your studies, at least for the time being, you should not use "postgraduate".

Comment: So can I introduce myself by saying I am an M.A in History from XYZ university ?  I have completed my M.A in 2016.@LPH

Comment: @cmi I think you can, but it is not the most elegant way to do that. "I have" is more idiomatic ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+am+an+MA%2CI+have+an+MA&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20am%20an%20MA%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20have%20an%20MA%3B%2Cc0)). Here is, for instance, another way: "I hold an MA, PhD, a Certificate and a Diploma in Coaching from the University of Warwick."; you might find that preferable.